# Вопрос по проектированию базы данных

Tags: база-данных

Проектирую очень большую базу данных, первый раз, в качестве академического интереса.

**Первый случай**

Есть таблица `people` с полями `id`, `name`, `surname`, `gender`

Человек мне предлагает создать отдельную `gender`, где нужно будет хранить пол. Но почему допустим нельзя хранить пол по ISO 5218:

```
0 — неизвестно
1 — мужчина
2 — женщина
9 — неприменимо
```

А уже на уровне веб-приложения, программы и так далее выводить название пола.

**Второй случай**

Есть таблица с песнями `track`, с полям `id`, `name`, `people_id`

Также я собираюсь хранить текст песни, и я предлагаю хранить её в отдельной таблице, но человек советует хранить в этой же таблице.

Но ведь выборку по имени или автору песни я произвожу часто и думаю нет смысла всё время подтягивать текст песни. Я лучше её буду подгружать отдельно, когда это необходимо.

Верны ли мои варианты? И хотелось бы услышать мнение, какой вариант лучше.

Comment: Первый да. Вы можете пол хранить как id и для самого пола даже создать отдельно таблицу. По второму тоже, можно хранить в отдельной таблице и только привязать по id  track. Все верно, никто не мшает разбивать таблицы на дробные и потом в запросе JOINить их

Comment: кто вас просит всегда подтягивать текст песни. поле из выборки исключите да и все. а по первому вопросу, вы можете использовать эти самые ID, и их же использовать в связной таблице. Таблица лишь дополнит понятность вашей БД.

Comment: Думаю, решающим фактором будет многолетняя статистика по запросам к такой БД: какие запросы делаются чаще - и на их основе выбирается полная нормализация или частичная денормализация. Где такую статистику взять? В похожих сервисах (если есть такая возможность), ну или со временем её накопить (и потом изменить схему БД, если понадобится).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Это очень плохая идея хардкодить какие-то значения в коде, а не держать их в базе, если они относятся к данным. Следовательно, если вы всегда выбираете с человеком и пол, то пол можно хранить прямо в этой же базе. Если нет, то тогда надо хранить отдельно.
2. В принципе лучше хранить её в той же таблице. Во время выборки просто исключите поле текста песни из выборки и тогда вы получите только имя. На производительность это не будет влиять.

Идея нормализации состоит в том, чтобы минимизировать повторяющиейся записи в таблице. Идея производительности, чтобы минимизировать и упростить выборки. Так вот хорошая БД - это баланс между первым и вторым.

Comment: ничего плохого в том чтобы определить константами 2 значения, которые в принципе не меняются и не расширяются нет.  Второй вопрос вы видимо не так поняли. Спрашивали не о хранении песни вместе с исполнителем, а о хранении текста песни вместе с самой песней.

Comment: @teran Спасибо.